# How do I map WTForms field for a db.Enum model on Flask-SQLAlchemy model?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, wtforms, flask-wtforms

Working with the following model:

```
class Recipe(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'recipe'
    __searchable__ = ['description']

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128), index=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(128))
    style = db.Column(db.Enum('fried', 'baked', 'roasted', 'mixed', name='cooking_style'))
    type = db.Column(db.Enum('breakfast', 'lunch', 'dinner', 'snack', 'sauce', 'bread', 'dessert', name='recipe_type'))
```

And the following:

```
form = CreateRecipeForm()
return render_template('create_client_recipe.html', form=form, client=c, recipe=r)
```

How do I represent `style` & `type` (both `db.Enum` fields) as a select field in the WTForm?

Answer (score 4):

Don't know if you need or not but I'm working with Flask-SQLAlchemy, I'm still a beginner, but I hope this can help you basically I created an Enum called state which has value 'Active' and 'Inactive', and I wanted to put this values in a form but I wanted to get the values from the database.

My model this one:

```
class StationhasBots(db.Model):
  "Many to Many table one raio station will have many functions"
  __tablename__ = 'station_has_bots'

  fk_radio_station_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('radio_station.id'), primary_key=True)
  fk_bot_functions_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('bot_functions.id'), primary_key=True)
  #Function is active or not
  state = db.Column(db.Enum('Active','Inactive',name='estado'),nullable=False)
  #In which time it will run
  run_frequency = db.Column(db.String(STRING_LEN),nullable=False)
  next_run = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True),nullable=False)
  #Source to fetch information
  source = db.Column(db.String,nullable=False)
  #path to the file that will be executed to pull info.
  path = db.Column(db.String,nullable=True)
  function_of_bots = db.relationship("BotsFunctions", backref=db.backref('function_from_bots'))
```

This is my form:

```
class AddBotForm(Form):
  station = QuerySelectField(query_factory=all_stations, allow_blank=False, blank_text='- select station-')
  function = QuerySelectField(query_factory=all_bot_functions, allow_blank=False, blank_text='- select function-')
  #state = SelectField(choices=[('active', 'Active'), ('inactive', 'Inactive')])
  state = SelectField(choices=[(g, g)for g in StationhasBots.state.property.columns[0].type.enums]) #Get the state from Station_has_Bots Table.
  next_run = DurationField(description=_("Duration , in HH:MM(:SS)"))
  run_frequency = HiddenField()
  source = StringField()
  path = StringField()
  submit = SubmitField(_('Save'))
```

In this form you can see that in the state field I run a query, this query will get the Enum called state that was created when I created the database.

To render the form I just did this in my views

```
@radio.route('/bots/add/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def bot_function_add():
   """Renders the form"""
   form = AddBotForm(request.form)
   program = None

   return render_template('radio/bot.html', program=program, form=form)
```

And then in templates did this

```
  <h2>{{ _('Add') }} {{ _('Bot') }}</h2>
        <form method="POST" action=""/>
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            {{ render_field(form, form.station) }}
            {{ render_field(form, form.function) }}
            {{ render_field(form, form.next_run) }} 
            {{ render_field(form, form.state) }}
            {{ render_field(form, form.source) }}
            {{ render_field(form, form.path) }}
            {{ render_field(form, form.submit) }}
        </form>
```

### *I think in your case something like this may work for you.*

```
 Type = SelectField(choices=[(g, g)for g in Recipe.type.property.columns[0].type.enums])
```

**First g**  -> Stays for value (in "HTML code")

**Second g** -> Is what will be presented to the user.

And then to render the form in your create_client_recipe.html file
you just need to do something like

```
{{ render_field(form, form.Type) }}
```

I know that six months have past since your post hope this can help some other people.

Comment: Many years later this answer helped me because I was having a similar issue!